# Laravel S3 File get contents

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

Inside of my Laravel application inside of my job class I have the following code. On my live server this code runs just fine however on my local I get an error and not sure what I need to do to fix this problem. Has anyone been able to solve this with using the AWS S3 file driver for Laravel?

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, file_get_contents($this->url), 'public');


file_get_contents(http://webapp.dev/storage/uploads/folder/folder/folder/imagename.jpeg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: And... Just pointing to the link doesn't tell me what I should be looking at.

Comment: Ah nvm, thought u had problems with local driver, anyhow, you can't access `AWS` from your `local` env by going to your `local` url for `storage`, you need to access the `url` that `AWS` generates for that file

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a webserver running locally that listens on port 80 for requests made to webapp.dev?

Does the directory for webapp.dev in fact have "imagename.jpeg" in that location?

This just looks like a 404 because that address doesn't exist on your local environment, but does exist on your live one.

Or, the context of $this is different on your local environment than it is on your production environment. We can't tell that from your original post, though, because you've only provided that one line and the resulting error.

Comment: I'm not sure what else would be needed to provide for this.

Comment: So if the answer to my first questions is yes, then the problem is probably related to $this.

Without needing to post anything more, you could troubleshoot this problem by trying to figure out why $this->url is resolving to that address, which is not responding with the expected data.

Comment: Its just crazy because the file exists where it says it is located.

Comment: And your local environment is in fact serving http://webapp.dev on port 80? Can you browse to that using a web browser?

Comment: What do you mean on port 80?

Comment: Port 80 is the standard network port for HTTP traffic. On your local environment, you need to be running a web server that is listening for traffic on port 80, otherwise you'll get that "Not found" error every time